# How to exit the estus soup room as a phantom?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I thought I'd be nice and show the host of embers the Undead Settlement [estus soup](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Estus+Soup) room (the one you fall down into in the mid-area room with lots of hanging bodies). But I can't open the door, even though most small doors can be opened as a phantom! Is this somehow intentional, a bug, or am I missing way of getting out (other than suicide or the Black Separation Crystal)?

Answer (score 4):

This is seems to be intended. Phantoms can't open doors (or at least they can't open one-way doors. This might be to prevent an experienced phantom from opening a useful shortcut). Your ways out would be:

- Have the Host of Embers notice all that delicious soup, so he comes down to taste it and opens the door himself
- Use the Black Separation Crystal to return to your world
- Use a spell that kills yourself (if you have any) to die and return to your world

Comment: I can't take the soup.

Comment: Ah right, phantoms can't pick up things either. Either way, if the Host doesn't notice, I'm afraid you're out of luck.